# Where can find the old webview interactive window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

My VSCode has updated to the newest version recently, however, I cannot see the webview interactive window and only the native interactive window. Inspecting the variables from the native interactive window is hard because it shows the variable at the terminate label, like figure 1. How can I fix this problem? figure 2 is the result of the webview interactive window

[image: img 1]

[image: img 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a big upgrade of `jupyter notebook`, you can have a look at [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/vscode-jupyter-notebooks-are-getting-an-upgrade-cc9aaaefc744).

If you really want to roll back to the older webview interactive window, you can install another version of `jupyter notebook` which before the version of `2.21.8.10xxxxx`(included).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have roll-backed to the older version (v2021.8.1236758218) and the problem has been resolved.

Comment: @Shan Fang Does it work? I thought it should be the version older than 2.21.8.10.